# UIImage imageWithData how to find image size and resize ratio

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two UIImages that need to be relative to each other, however I dont know how to calculate tha ration of the UIImage size that I have set to the actual size of the image I am receiving in Base64 data.

Currently I am doing this with no calculation of the change in size of the original imageview and currently the profileImageView is much much bigger than it needs to be as its not dynamic.

```
if ([recivedRquestType isEqualToString:@"FaceBlank"]) {
        FaceBlankImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        imageView = nil;
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:FaceBlankImage];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 70.0, ScreenWidth, (ScreenHeight/2)-75);

        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        // call profile
        [engineRequests GetImageK:currProfile RequestType:@"Profile" NavController:self.navigationController];

    } else if   ([recivedRquestType isEqualToString:@"Profile"]) {
        profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        [profileImageView removeFromSuperview];
        profileImageView = nil;
        profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:profileImage];
        profileImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        profileImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, (ScreenHeight/2)-10, ScreenWidth/2, 50.0);

        [self.view addSubview:profileImageView];
    }
```

This works by putting everything in the correct position its just that the ratio of image ones adjustment is not the same as the profileImage, and I need to get them the same.

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` has a `size` property, which is a `CGSize` struct. That should give you the width and height of the image itself.

It also has two other properties called `scale` and `resizingMode`, and you may want to check those out too.

Comment: Awesome! will check those out now!